# Trying to understand these old German records from 1897 for a genealogy project

Tags: translation, german-to-english, handwriting, kurrent

I'm doing some genealogy work and found someone who I think can help me dive deeper but I can't read it at all. Any help would be so greatly appreciated :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to German.SE! A few notes: 1. It is customary and expected here to describe (share) *what research you have already done* (if any). Did you already transcribe parts of it? 2. Do you already have some background info, f.i. could you share the *names of the people and places* involved? (Proper names can be harder to decipher than "normal" text, so this would spare us *guesswork*). 3. Do you happen to have a *better-quality* version of scan no. 2 (less compressed and pixelated?)

Comment: Hi Marquinho, thank you for informing of the proper etiquette on this site. I'm currently researching my religious history and last name, "Marta". After taking a DNA test I was surprised to learn that I am Jewish on my fathers side but am unsure of where this ancestry traces to. Additionally, the surname Marta is rather uncommon and has always been mistaken for hispanic-origin. Stanislaus Marta was the furthest I could trace back and it was exciting to learn that the surname was recorded improperly after immigration, as his surname is "Merda". I appreciate your help in my learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. 11

Neuhöfchen am 24. Mai 1897.

Vor dem unterzeichneten Standesbeamten erschien heute, der Persönlichkeit nach bekannt, die Frau Marie Merda geborene Waczowska

wohnhaft zu Jordan

und zeigte an, dass der Arbeiter Stanislaus Merda 42 Jahre alt katholischer Religion,

wohnhaft zu Jordan

geboren zu Lomnitz Kreis Meseritz verheirathet gewesen mit der Anzeigenden

Sohn des Arbeiters Anton Merda und dessen Ehefrau Marie geborene (unbekannt) beide gestorben in Lomnitz

zu Jordan in der Wohnung der Anzeigenden

am Vier und Zwanzigsten Mai des Jahres tausend acht hundert neunzig und sieben Vormittags um Neun Uhr verstorben sei.

Die Anzeigende erklärte, dass sie aus eigener Wissenschaft vom vorbezeichneten Todesfall unterrichtet sei.

Vorgelesen, genehmigt und von der Anzeigenden wegen Schreibensunkunde mit ihrem Handzeichen versehen.

+++

Der Standesbeamte.

(?) Motzig

---

Neuhöfchen: [Wiki-Link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowy_Dworek,_Lubusz_Voivodeship)

Jordan: [Wiki-Link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordanowo,_Lubusz_Voivodeship)

Meseritz: [Wiki-Link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreis_Meseritz)

Comment: Wow, thank you Dr. Standesbeamte! This was incredibly informative. I appreciate you linking the towns as well :) Hoping to travel to Poland one day soon

Comment: typos: "aus eigner Wossenschaft" is "aus eig**e**ner W**i**ssenschaft"

Comment: @amarta1, “Der Standesbeamte” is part of the text, the line above the signature.

Answer (score 5):

No. 11

Neuhöfchen am 24. Mai 1897.

Vor dem unterzeichneten Standesbeamten erschien heute, der

Persönlichkeit nach

bekannt,

die Frau Maria Merda geborene Warzowska

wohnhaft zu Jordan

und zeigte an, daß der Arbeiter Stanislaus Merda

42 Jahre alt katholischer Religion,

wohnhaft in Jordan

geboren zu Lomnitz Kreis Meseritz verheiratet

gewesen mit der Anzeigenden

Sohn des Arbeiters Anton Merda und

dessen Ehefrau Marie geborene (unbekannt) beide

gestorben in Lomnitz

zu Jordan in der Wohnung der Anzeigenden

am Vier und Zwanzigsten Mai

des Jahres tausend achthundert neunzig und Sieben

Vormittags um Neun Uhr

verstorben sei.

Die Anzeigende erklärte, dass sie aus eigener

Wissenschaft von dem vorbezeichneten Todesfall unterrichtet sei.

Vorgelesen, genehmigt und von der Anzeigenden wegen

Schreibensunkunde mit ihrem Handzeichen versehen.

+++

Der Standesbeamte.

(?) Motzig

**Remark:**

It seems that Maria Merda was illiterate (*Schreibensunkunde*). The three crosses are her "signature" (*Handzeichen*).

Concerning the locations see https://gov.genealogy.net/item/show/object_1042833.

**Update:**

As pointed out by marquinho, the maiden name of Mrs. Merda was very likely "Waczowska" and not "Warzowska" as I wrote above.
Moreover, her first name was most likely "Marie" and not "Maria" as I wrote above.
In fact I realized that the handwriting of the civil registrar has a special feature: Names of persons and localities are written in a sort of cursive script, the rest of the text is written in the traditional German Kurrent. For example look at "die Frau Maria Merda" and you will see the differences between the letters "d, e" in "die" and in "Merda", similarly "r,a" in "Frau" and in "Marie".
Having ignored this, I was initially convinced that the last letter of "Marie" cannot be an "e", but must be an "a".

Comment: The transcription "Werda" (which you, too, have used in one place) seems much more plausible to me. As for the maiden name, I'd suggest "Waczowska" rather than "Warzowska".

Comment: @marquinho Concerning "Waczowska" you are probably right. But I doubt that it is "Werda" (which I didn't use in my transcription). Look at the letter "W" in *Waczowska*).

Comment: Yes, you have a point regarding the "W". And I really thought I had read "Sohn des Arbeiters Anton Werda" - sorry about that!

Comment: I recall having corrected this is my post, you must have mistaken mine for Paul's. I should also add that I had several empty spots, Paul's doesn't apart from Marie's maiden name - which is a mystery on its own, with Warzowska being a somewhat popular name, related to Warsaw, and Waczowska almost unheard of.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. Is it possible that "Werda" could be "Merda" as other records indicate that as a surname? Also super interesting to learn about Marie, she is a new person in my genealogy search

Comment: @amarta1: The reading "Werda" was just a hypothesis of mine – I think we all came to the consensus that "Merda" is correct.

Comment: Re: "Names of persons and localities are written in a sort of cursive script, the rest of the text is written in the traditional German [Kurrentschrift]†". *Exactly!* That is a *nearly universal and constant feature* of German handwriting in the Modern Era: Names, addresses, sometimes dates are usually written in Antiqua (the "Latin"/Italian/French script). The same goes for Latin or French loanwords. (I don't have internet sources at hand, unfortunately, but this is a well-known feature). (†Not all Kurrentschrift is "Sütterlin" btw; the latter was a rather short-lived invention from 1911.)

Comment: @marquinho Interesting, I was not aware of this feature. I also replaced "Sütterlin" by "Kurrent".